# Which method is the best for developing Excel sheet as ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my company, we have a big excel sheet that we use it as a data entry. This matrix is filled with the data by many employees. each employee is required to fill specfic cells in that data entry. Now, we want to automate this matrix by developing a web-based system that contains this matrix. I am new ASP.NET developer and I just developed two systems with it. Now, I want to know what is the proper way to develop this matrix and if there is any example that can help me in this issue.

Should I use one of the controls like GridView, ListView or DetailsView for this issue? Which technique I should use for developing this?

Comment: I'd use ASP.NET MVC 3, as opposed to just ASP.NET...

Comment: My I recommend putting the data in the Excel spreadsheet in a database.  SQL Server perhaps.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out jqGrid, the open source version at: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

Answer (score 2):

Just because you currently use a spreadsheet now doesn't mean that you should limit your replacement application to the same paradigm.

I recommend that you use the current application only as a way to discover from the users what the real requirements are. This is especially true since spreadsheets tend to just grow in complexity over time, without anyone sitting down and deciding on what the overall requirements are. If you do that now, you may very well find that the application that you design based on these requirements looks nothing like the spreadsheet you started from, yet meets the requirements more completely, and with better customer satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project consists of two parts: Reporting Pages and Data Entry Pages.

I would not recommend putting one giant matrix on the screen and allowing everyone to edit it.
Rather I would suggest you create several entry forms for each unique entry scenario and have the forms write to a database and then have that data drive reports.  This way you have more control over each form and can easily automate for every scenario.

For the reports, if you are using asp.net web forms, a GridView control can render data fine for reporting. However, keep in mind that if you have an extremely large amount of data you may run into performance issues.  You can look into 3rd party controls if this is the case or use SSRS if you have access to it.  Another idea is to just allow users to export the report to excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you show the whole matrix in the webpage, just like you had been doing with the Excel file itself, it will be quite cumbersome.In stead, while moving to an automated online system, you should try to limit the UI on per user basis; that is, create and show only the related part of the UI to the particular employee and then take that input data and either write it to Excel file or to database.

If you think, you ultimately need to create the Excel file from this input then you may try using [Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) to [import the captured data to Excel worksheet](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/importing-data-to-worksheets.html). You may first put the input data into DataSet, DataTable or Array etc. and then import that data easily. I hope this might help.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.